# ZF2 second round of bootstrapping

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How would I be able to subscribe to events in a way such that a second round of bootstrapping would be possible in one of my modules, making sure all modules have had their `onBootstrap()` methods already called?

I have already tried subscribing to the same `onBootstrap()` event from within my Module's `onBootstrap()`, but with a lower priority. That didn't work; apparently the events that are to be triggered are determined before triggering any, and therefore you cannot subscribe to the same event that is currently being triggered and expect it to work.

I also wanted to try to subscribe to `loadModules.post` within `init()`, and then subscribe to  `EVENT_BOOTSTRAP`, but I realized I couldn't find any way to access `$mvcEvent`, and in turn, `$application`, and in turn, the application event manager where the subscription needs to take place on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do exactly this just the other day.

You're right that you can't attach in the `onBootstrap` event, you need to attach a listener in the `init` method instead, and you need to use the shared manager to listen to the `MvcEvent` being triggered by the application

```
public function init(ModuleManager $modules)
{
    // attach to the end of the bootstrap event
    $modules->getEventManager()
            ->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP, function ($e) {
                 // do something after everything else has bootstrapped

             }, -1000);
}
```